# Intellij Terminal does not recognize the mvn / java / gradle commands

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, terminal, command

When I use the commands like `java --v` or `mvn -v` locally, it works. But when I use it in the IntelliJ IDEA terminal does not recognize them.

Local:

[image: Local]

IntelliJ IDEA terminal:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA terminal]

The environment variables:

[image: The environment variables]

Path:

[image: path]

IntelliJ IDEA recognizes the java classes and the maven dependencies were imported correctly.

The IntelliJ IDEA terminal is supposed to work like the windows terminal.

Comment: Check the actual value of %PATH%

Comment: And please try to share error message in plain text format

Answer (score 0):

Check Terminal settings under Settings (Preferences on macOS) -> Tools -> Terminal.
Make sure "Include system environmental variables" option is selected.
If the option is selected and it still doesn't work, try copying PATH values to the "User environment variables" section.

Another thing you can try is to [run IDE from cmd](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011901879-How-to-start-IDE-from-the-command-line)